# Typescript string to enum conversion error

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need to convert string(UrlStatus) to enum(Status).

```
export enum Status {
  available,
  inProgress
}

export type UrlStatus = 'available' | 'inprogress';

// something wrong here
export const UrlStatusToStatus: { [UrlStatus]: Status } = {
  available: [Status.available],
  inprogress: [Status.inProgress]
}
```

I am getting this error when trying to use `UrlStatusToStatus[status] //status's type is UrlStatus`

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'UrlStatus' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  Property 'available' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is just slightly off:

```
enum Status {
  available = 1,
  inProgress = 2
};

type UrlStatus = 'available' | 'inprogress';

const UrlStatusToStatus: { [key in UrlStatus]: Status } = {
    available: Status.available,
    inprogress: Status.inProgress
};

console.log(UrlStatusToStatus['inprogress']);
```

Output:

> 2